# Jbehave - @BeforeScenario how to identify scenario

Tags: java, testing, bdd, jbehave, gherkin

is it possible to execute something before a specific scenario runs? 
e.g in the example below i want to execute a piece of code before `Scenario: 2 - Bar` runs:

```
Scenario: 1 - Foo

Given a Foo
When run
Then success

Scenario: 2 - Bar

Given a Bar
When run
Then fail
```

I know that `@BeforeScenario` might do the job, I just don't know how to identify the scenario.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Meta: @id scenario1` will do the job